# Is there any good node.js IDE for mac?

Tags: macos, node.js

recently, I started studying node.js

.. my favorite IDE is eclipse, I guess everyone does like it.

However, when I installed nodeclipse plugin to Juno, yes, it worked,but no as fancy as I expected.

I searched and found webmatrix2 is quite good for node.js.

So, I'm going to try it.

Anyway,, my question is if there is any good ide for mac....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse is an option with the nodeclipse plugin. Visit: http://www.nodeclipse.org/

I still prefer Webstorm by JetBrains. They have a work-in-progress browser debugger as well.

Comment: Plus, Webstorm can support a popular template engine, Jade through a plugin install.

Answer (score 8):

This is a pretty old post, but I came across it in my search.

For people of the future, I would recommend https://atom.io

It has great git support and tons of cool plugins.

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio Code is a great IDE for Node.js and Javascript. It is based on GitHub's Atom editor.

https://code.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 3):

Try [inteliJ Idea 12.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) it has nice [node.js](http://plugins.jetbrains.net/plugin/?webide&pluginId=6098) plugin.

I use it right now. Idea has so much cool features. When you start to use it you forget about other Ides))

Answer (score 3):

The node plugin is not supported on MacOS. See [this page](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17349802-node-js-project-support) if you'd like to vote for MS to add support to VS on MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

Webstorm is pretty good and popular, and works on OSX: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: Very good IDE. If the money is not a problem and want to program in more languages, IDEA would be better. In node, both are the same sweet IDE.

Comment: Taking into account possibility to buy it for 25$ makes it no brainer

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if anyone has mentioned this but I found this today when searching for IDE for Node.js.

It's called Nide (http://coreh.github.io/nide/).

Seems to be dedicated just for Node.js, although the trade off is, there's no native Windows or Linux version yet but apparently you can run it through or web browser, otherwise if you're on a Mac, you can install the native application dmg.

Just a note of warning: it's still in its early stages so don't depend your mission critical projects on it just yet! :P

Answer (score 1):

node-mirror is worth a shot. it has 
- syntax highlighting
- error checking
- a terminal
- and a very rudimentary node.js debugger which is in development right now.

https://npmjs.org/package/node-mirror

Comment: I think it's appropriate to indicate that you're the author of node-mirror.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have just announced [Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/) (as opposed to Visual Studio Code) and there is a plugin for Node.js.

Comment: How can I add Node.js plugin in Visual studio for Mac?

Comment: Duck Duck 'Visual Studio Node Tools'

Comment: Do I need to install Visual studio as well? or can I use the Visual studio for mac only? I'm getting .msi file when I download the node.js tool and I couldn't install it on my mac :(

Comment: This is not for Mac!!

Comment: As Marco Antonio said, .msi files are for windows, not mac.

Comment: Note that they are now retiring this on August 31, 2024

Answer (score 1):

Try Webstorm from jetbrains.It comes with a pretty nice auto complete.Here is the [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) .But it comes with a price.If you need a free IDE,go for atom.io.